# header Location: function not working in my code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webform with basic info  (`Fname, Lname, Uname, Email, Phumber, Age, Facebook, Major, Education, Music, Fav, message`)

After submitting the form, and inserting the data of those fields into a MySQL database, I want to be able to be redirected to a different URL.
I tried using the header function for PHP but for some reason it will not redirect me to the URL I specified.

```
    <?php
ob_start();
require("config.php");
include 'config.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
if($_GET['action'] == 'check')
{
   if($_POST['Fname'] == '' || $_POST['Lname'] == '' || $_POST['Uname'] == '' || $_POST['Email'] == '' || $_POST['Phumber'] == '' || $_POST['Age'] == '' || $_POST['Facebook'] == '' || $_POST['Major'] == '' || $_POST['Education'] == '' || $_POST['Music'] == '' || $_POST['Fav'] == '' || $_POST['message'] == '')
   {
      exit;
   }
   else
   {
if($_POST['Email'] !== $_POST['Email'])
         {
         exit;
         }
      else
         {
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loginphp
         WHERE Uname='{$_POST['Uname']}'") or die(mysql_error()); 
         $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
         if($row['Uname'] == '')
            {
            $_Fname = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Fname']);
            $_Lname = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Lname']);
            $_Uname = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Uname']);
            $_Email = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Email']);
$_Phumber = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Phumber']);
$_Age = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Age']);
$_Facebook = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Facebook']);
$_Major = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Major']);
$_Education = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Education']);
$_Music = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Music']);
$_Fav = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['Fav']);
$_message = str_replace("<", "", $_POST['message']);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO loginphp 
            (Fname, Lname, Uname, Email, Phumber, Age, Facebook, Major, Education, Music, Fav, message) VALUES('$_Fname', '$_Lname', '$_Uname', '$_Email', '$_Phumber', '$_Age', '$_Facebook', '$_Major', '$_Education', '$_Music', '$_Fav', '$_message') ") 
            or die(mysql_error());
header("Location: main.php");
exit();
    }
}
}   
}
?>
```

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at register.php:1) in register.php on line 47

-------------- The answer

This problem doesn't want to get solved so I add print with html code to redirect the page after insert the data to solve it

```
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO loginphp 
            (Fname, Lname, Uname, Email, Phumber, Age, Facebook, Major, Education, Music, Fav, message) VALUES('$_Fname', '$_Lname', '$_Uname', '$_Email', '$_Phumber', '$_Age', '$_Facebook', '$_Major', '$_Education', '$_Music', '$_Fav', '$_message') ") 
            or die(mysql_error());
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.http://stackoverflow.com/">';
exit();
```

Thanks for everyone tried to help !

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to first line of code and get errors or warnings temporarily.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /register.php:1) in /register.php on line 89

Comment: /register.php on line 89 is header("Location: main.php");

Comment: move your if block to bellow of `require("config.php");`

Comment: can you be more clear with my please ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all output before header like `echo` or `print`

And use exit after header.

```
 header("Location: main.php");
 exit();
```

Update

If you turn on output buffering you can output in the script but PHP doesn't have to send the headers until the buffer is flushed. ... Check something with echo , print() or printr() in the file. It might be that this is the problem OR if any file, then check the number of spaces.

```
  $form = "<br>";
  //show the form
  $form .="<center>";
  $form .= '<form method .....';
```

......
......

And write this at last line before `?>`

```
   echo $form;
```

Comment: didn't work. also I can't delete all the prints or echo before the line header !

Comment: First try by removing those  echos, you will see its working.

Comment: Although you written code wrongly. You can store all output in a variable and echo it after header. Be sure to use exit after header.

Comment: Help me to fix the code

Comment: Updated my answers.  It's my last comment. I gonna die.

Comment: I tried what you wrote and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You must remove all of `echo`, `print_r` and `var_dump` functions before changing header. In your case, if you don't have `echo` like functions in `config.php` file, you can try this one:

```
//ini_set('display_errors', 1); commented in editing
ob_start();
//include the header
require("config.php");
if($_GET['action'] == 'check'){
//your code
}
//other codes (echo and print and vardump)
```

It's better to use template engines like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

Comment: I tried what you told me, but the page didn't even show up ! also I don't have any print .. etc inside the file config.php

Comment: possibly you have BOM character (invisible) in first of file. remove it with `awk` or `Notepadd++`.

Comment: Yes I just checked the first file and I notiected that I had Bom character inside it. and I removed them. But the problem didn't fix.

Do you want to contact me on skype ? if that's okay with you ?

Comment: @user7420580 we can communicate together in stackoverflow to help everyone that have a common question. you can update question to make an obvious one.

Comment: @user7420580 it's not relevant to your code structure. if you have an output before `header`, it does not work. reg.html or any other files.

Comment: I updated the code. there's no echo, print, printer above the error line. and this problem didn't get fixed !

Comment: `if($_POST['Email'] !== $_POST['Email'])` ?
and now add `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` to disable printing warning and errors before sending header.

Comment: if($_POST['Email'] !== $_POST['Email']), I used this code for password then I removed password and I add email so I can have time to find a solution for the problem. Also I turned it off but the problems still doesn't want to get fixed. I don't have output so I don't really know what is the problem. I start thinking to just program a new file. but I really want to know what is the problem of this code.